# Updatedb on samba mounted shares

Tags: samba, recursive, updatedb

I have a few directories mounted from a samba share server (my lan storage) and I would like to run updatedb on them.
I use to successfully run such command to do that:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.myDbFile.db -U /mnt/myCustomDirectory/
```

under `/mnt/myCustomDirectory/` there are, individual mounted samba shares, such as:

```
/mnt/myCustomDirectory/Music
/mnt/myCustomDirectory/Video
/mnt/myCustomDirectory/Backup
```

and so on.

After a fresh installation of the latest linux Mint 19.2 (same as Ubuntu 18.04), the `.myDbFile.db` is empty and nothing gets indexed.

If instead I run the command on a single share, the dbFile gets indexed:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.myDbFile_Music.db -U /mnt/myCustomDirectory/Music
```

Any idea why the first command does not work recursive into the single folders?

Comment: Maybe because `smbfs` is in the `PRUNEFS` list, but by specifying a file below the mount point you skip over that check?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I figured out in the end.

For updatedb, I loop over the single directories mounted and create a specific db file:

```
alias updatedb_lanserver='cd /mnt/myCustomDirectory; for folder in *; do updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.lan_server_$folder.db -U $folder; done'
```

To search all these db files at once I created a bash function:

```
locate_lanserver() { for dbfile in ~/.lan_server*.db; do locate -d $dbfile -i $1; done }
```

now I can simply use the function to search something:

```
locate_lanserver text_to_be_searched
```

Comment: editing `/etc/updatedb.conf` would probably be the simpler and faster solution